# Can I trigger more than one function on single click event?

Tags: javascript, function, events

I wanted two functions to be triggerd on a single click event in JavaScript. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes just create a single function that is called on click which calls two functions.

```
function clickHandlerFunction() {
    function1();
    function2();
}
```

Or register more than one event listener, whichever takes your fancy. They are both appropriate in different situations.

If you would like the ability to add or remove one of the functions then registering as seperate listeners will allow you to later remove a particular listener.  The method above would allow you to either have all or none of the functions invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can register more than one event listener.

```
 yourElement.addEventListener("click", function1, false); 
 yourElement.addEventListener("click", function2, false);
```

Comment: I would +1 if you gave an example. :)

Comment: Jon Taylor answer is good and may be more easy to understand.